# React Native detox record user interactions for test script

Tags: ios, react-native, detox

I'm using [detox](https://github.com/wix/detox) to test a react native app in iOS. (Detox is written on top of [EarlGrey](https://github.com/google/EarlGrey)).

I prefer to use Detox's [by.id matcher](https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.Matchers.md#byidid) which uses React Native's testID (iOS's accessibility ID)

What I am having trouble with is the amount of time it takes to find the proper testIDs on each page in my app to write the test cases.  Is there a way to record my user interactions so that I can 
quickly generate a detox test script?  I'm largely in the simulator clicking on various buttons.  Alternatively is there a way to quickly view testIDs in the react native app while it is running?

I have tried the following which I find very slow:

1. When a detox test case fails it prints an error log with the UI hierarchy in the log.  While helpful I find this a slow way to find test IDs.
2. The React Native inspector lets me view various UI elements by clicking them on the page.  Unfortunately it does not list testID so I have to scan through the code to see what value is being passed as testID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to record my user interactions so that I can quickly
> generate a detox test script?
>
> **- Not as far as I know**

You can try react-devtools to find testIDs.

https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools

```
npm i -g react-devtools
```

After installing run react-devtools in terminal.

```
react-devtools
```

You still need to Toggle Inspector, but you will now be able to use React Developer Tools UI to explore React DOM tree like this:

[image: password input example]